# Can I register a .it domain name for a company outside of Italy?

Tags: domain-name

I've got a domain name that would work nicely with a .it domain name (e.g. redd.it).  This is for a web application I'm building, which if it ever generates revenue will be for a company in the US.  Is this allowed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about domain name registration, not programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to their [FAQ](http://www.nic.it/en/faq/faq-nomi.html#nomi6), you need to have an office within EU.

Comment: I've personally registered a .it domain myself and I'm definitely not a business nor based in italy.

Comment: This is not true at all. You just need to be an EU citizen.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to register one with [Europe Registry](http://www.europeregistry.com/). It takes a few days but you can get one. The way it works is *they* are registered Italian business, and they act as your agent.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an EU citizen, but I've managed to get one *.it* domain paying an additional trustee vendor fee from a famous domain registrar.

[Their FAQ](https://www.godaddy.com/help/about-it-domain-names-5358) shows the following requirements to get an *.it* domain:

> - If your country of origin is Italy, you must enter the Registrant
>     Fiscal Code.
> - If your country is within the European Union, you must
>     enter the Identity Document Number, or the numerals that display on an
>     official form of identification.
> - If you do not meet the residency
>     requirements, we automatically charge you a trustee vendor fee of
>     $19.99 per year. The trustee helps you meet the residency requirement
>     and is a third-party vendor. If someone contacts the trustee with an
>     issue regarding your domain name, the trustee contacts us, and then we
>     contact you.
>
> NOTE: When our trustee service is used for a .it domain
>   registration, the trustee service will review the registration request
>   within 24 hours of purchase. They do this to prevent trademark
>   infringement and reduce the number of disputes or legal issues.
>
> If the registration request is approved, the domain name will complete
>   registration, but if the registration request is denied, the domain
>   name will not be registered and all registration fees will be
>   refunded.

Answer (score 3):

This is the corresponding ccTLD page: [nic.it](http://www.nic.it/en/domini/index.html). I have went over their rules and, besides several restricted categories, there do not seem do be limitations on registration.

Answer (score -2):

Yes unless there is a specific rule for Italy... There are tons of sites that use other country's domain but is physically located at other country.